# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00902: invalid datatype

Tags: java, sql, oracle, exception

I'm trying to create a table from servlet. But wen i run, it was showing the error `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00902: invalid datatype`. But when i execute the same query in sql plus it was executing .

stack trace :

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00902: invalid datatype
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:439)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:395)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:802)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:436)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:521)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:194)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:1000)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1307)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdateInternal(OracleStatement.java:1814)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdate(OracleStatement.java:1779)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OracleStatementWrapper.java:277)
at skypark.CreateUserAc.doGet(CreateUserAc.java:126)
at skypark.CreateUserAc.doPost(CreateUserAc.java:345)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
at skypark.Registration.doPost(Registration.java:137)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:931)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And my code is :

```
  Statement stC=con.createStatement();
    StringBuilder sbC=new StringBuilder(1024);
    sbC.append("create table ").append(uname).append("COMMENTS(UNAME VARCHAR2(50),COMMENTS VARCHAR2(1100),ITEMID NUMBER)");
    String QueryC=sbC.toString();
    stC.executeUpdate(QueryC);         //stack trace showing error

    Statement stCH=con.createStatement();
    StringBuilder sbCH=new StringBuilder(1024);
    sbCH.append("create table ").append(uname).append("CHAT(ID NUMBER NOT NULL,FROM VARCHAR2(50),TO VARCHAR2(50),MESSAGE VARCHAR2(500) DEFAULT NULL NOT NULL,SENT DATE NOT NULL, RECD NUMBER)");
    String QueryCH=sbCH.toString();
    stCH.executeUpdate(QueryCH);     //stack trace showing error
```

Please anyone tell me what mistake i made.........thanks.......

Comment: Can you try `stC.execute()` ? Link: http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-statement-example-create-a-table/

Comment: What is `COMMENTS(UNAME VARCHAR2(50)` supposed to achieve? Sounds like a strange column definition.

Comment: The syntax is `create table foo (col1 ...)` ***NOT*** `create table(foo(col1...)`

Comment: I suspect the code you run successfully in SQL*Plus is not the same your StringBuilder contains.

Comment: I got the problem `from` is reserved word.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are missing a closing `')'` in both statements, try to delete the opening `'('` before the table name.

EDIT:

In the second statement you are using arods like ID, FROM, TO, etc, these are often keywords which can cause conflicts. The column **MESSAGE** ist defined as *default null* then *not null*:

```
create table (CHAT(ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
              FROM VARCHAR2(50),
              TO VARCHAR2(50),
              MESSAGE VARCHAR2(500) DEFAULT NULL NOT NULL,  
              SENT DATE NOT NULL, RECD NUMBER)
```

Comment: @James - Perhaps you should inspect the *generated* SQL code, rather than the Java code you use to generate it. Errors will probably become more obvious.

Comment: @James did you add a closing bracket on the second statement too?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're a victim of a cut'n'paste error somewhere;

```
sbC.append("create table ").append(uname)
   .append("(COMMENTS(UNAME VARCHAR2(50),COMMENTS VARCHAR2(1100),ITEMID NUMBER)");
```

...will lead to an SQL statement similar to;

```
create table uname_table (
  COMMENTS(UNAME VARCHAR(50),     <-- strange indeed, cut'n'paste?
  COMMENTS VARCHAR2(1100),
  ITEMID NUMBER
)
```

Something more reasonable would be;

```
sbC.append("create table ").append(uname)
   .append("(UNAME VARCHAR2(50),COMMENTS VARCHAR2(1100),ITEMID NUMBER)");
```

...which would give;

```
create table uname_table (
  UNAME VARCHAR(50),
  COMMENTS VARCHAR2(1100),
  ITEMID NUMBER
)
```